# Understanding google maps urls

Tags: google-maps

i'd like to extract latitude and longitude values from google map links.

let's say you have the following link (this is the link that you'd get on http://maps.google.com link menu)

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=tokyo&aq=&sll=35.675147,-95.712891&sspn=47.800848,92.724609&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Tokyo,+Japan&t=h&z=9

there are a couple of lat/lon values here (sll, sspn) but none of them seems right.
In this case the first pair links to Mongolia the second goes to Oklahoma.

the correct lat/lon would be around 35.6894875, 139.6917064.

my question is that how you can get this values from a link?

I found this site http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters
but i could not really figure out the solution.

thanks and best,
 Viktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of ll in your URL should be the latitude and longitude of the center of your map.  Unfortunately, your URL does not have an ll parameter.  When I go to Google Maps, map a location, and click the link button to get a URL to share, it invariably has the ll parameter.  I'm not sure how you generated the above URL, but that might have a clue to the solution.

Comment: hi, thanks, but is the lat/lon you get with the LL parameter same as the location of the pin?

Comment: The ll parameter is the center of your map.  So, if the pin is in the center of your map, then yes, ll will be the location of the pin.  If not, then not.